# Subtract months from date in velocity

Tags: date, calendar, velocity, vtl

I am trying to get the date a certain number of months ago from a given date

I've tried converting to Calendar to then use the add method, but that didn't work:

```
#set( $myCalendar =  $date.toCalendar($endDate))
#set( $startdate = $calendarstart.add("MONTH", -$minusMonths))
```

I've tried to do this in a few different ways:

```
#set( $temp =  0 - $numberOfMissedPremiums)
#evaluate($calendarstart.add( 2 , $temp ))
```

```
#set( $a = $calendarstart.add( 2 , $temp ))
```

I've even tried defining blocks, but that didn't work either

Comment: Write the language as a tag please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Calendar.add() method takes an int, not a string, for the field indicator. To change the months, you need the Calendar.MONTH method, which is 2.

So you would write:

```
#set( $startdate = $calendarstart.clone() )
$startdate.add(2, -$minusMonths)
```

Also, if you're still using Velocity 1.7, you may need to write:

```
#set( $startdate = $calendarstart.clone() )
#set( $temp = 0 - $minusMonths )
$startdate.add(2, $temp)
```

To nicify a bit this code, you can use the [FieldTool](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/3.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/FieldTool.html), which you can configure like this:

```
<tools>
  <toolbox scope="application">
    <tool key = "cal"
          class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.FieldTool"
          include="java.util.Date"/>
  </toolbox>
</tools>
```

So you can now write:

```
#set( $startdate = $calendarstart.clone() )
$startdate = $calendarstart.add($cal.MONTH, -$minusMonths)
```

(and I let you adapt the 1.7 version).

As a final note, please take a moment to consider moving this code to a Java tool. VTL is a template language, and what you are trying to do seems more like a business logic task.

(*Edited*) As noted in @luis-rico first comment, `Calendar.add()` returns void. Calendar is a *mutable* object, so if you want to keep the original Calendar instance, you will have to clone it first. Then you can directly call `$startdate.add(2, -$minusMonth)` in the template, since void results aren't printed.

Comment: The problem is that the Calendar.add() method returns void, so it cannot be used like that, i tried using #set without assigning it to a variable, but gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I finally managed to get it working:

```
#set( $minusmonths =  $math.mul($numberOfMonthsToSubtract,-1))    
#set( $Mycalendar = $date.getCalendar())   
#set( $Dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd" )
$Mycalendar.setTime($convert.parseDate(
    $endDate, 
    $Dateformat
  ))
#set( $calConst = $field.in($Mycalendar) )
$Mycalendar.add($calConst.MONTH, $minusmonths.intValue())
```

---

The problem seemed to be on the Calendar.add() not parsing the value correctly, it only accepts Int and was receiving a Number.

The way I defined the calendar variable was giving some problems as well.