# Find the end of current month with Velocity

Tags: calendar, velocity, marketo

I've just started to use Marketo's mail scripting, 
and I need to find out the last of the current month.

I could find the current date as below.How can I do further?

```
#set($date = $date.calendar)
#set($current_date = $date.format('yyyy-mm-dd', $date.getTime()))
$current_date
```

Refer to here,
[Subtract months from date in velocity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734839/subtract-months-from-date-in-velocity/56760590#56760590)
I tried to subtract 1 day from the beginning of next month, but it doesn't work.

Knowing the number of days in this month is also meets the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method you tried should work. I think that your problem is that you are overwriting `$date` - which initially contains the `DateTool` - with your working variable. When Velocity Tools `org.apache.velocity.tools.userCanOverwriteTools` configuration value is `true` (which is the default) Velocity will let you overwrite `$date` but the `DateTool` will be unavailable thereafter.

So try changing your working variable to `$cal` for instance. Then, you have several methods:

```
#set($cal = $date.calendar)
$cal.add(2, 1)
$cal.set(5, 1)
$cal.add(5, -1)
$date.format('yyyy-MM-dd', $cal)
```

or

```
#set($cal = $date.calendar)
$cal.set(5, $cal.getActualMaximum(5))
$date.format('yyyy-MM-dd', $cal)
```

In all cases, you resort to using the `Calendar.MONTH` and `Calendar.DATE` constants (respectively 2 and 5). You may want to put such utility operations in a Java tool of your own to have more readable templates.